# Backup When Closing File Excel 2010 VBA

Tags: excel, backup, vba

I want Excel to automatically backup a workbook on file close without prompts to the user. I found the excellent code below online (forgot source) but the backup FileType is changing to a BAK File that I cannot open. How do I fix this problem. Both files will be in the same folder & the backup should have same file name & "-bak" or ".bak".

```
Sub SaveWorkbookBackup()

Dim awb As Workbook, BackupFileName As String, i As Integer, OK As Boolean
   If TypeName(ActiveWorkbook) = "Nothing" Then Exit Sub
   Set awb = ActiveWorkbook
   If awb.Path = "" Then
      Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
   Else
      BackupFileName = awb.FullName
      i = 0
      While InStr(i + 1, BackupFileName, ".") > 0
         i = InStr(i + 1, BackupFileName, ".")
    Wend
    If i > 0 Then BackupFileName = Left(BackupFileName, i - 1)
    BackupFileName = BackupFileName & ".bak"
    OK = False
    On Error GoTo NotAbleToSave
    With awb
        Application.StatusBar = "Saving this workbook..."
        .Save
        Application.StatusBar = "Saving this workbook backup..."
        .SaveCopyAs BackupFileName
        OK = True
    End With
  End If
NotAbleToSave:
   Set awb = Nothing
   Application.StatusBar = False
   If Not OK Then
    MsgBox "Backup Copy Not Saved!", vbExclamation, ThisWorkbook.Name
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: updated answer to turn off alerts if you are going to be overwriting per your request

Comment: @DougGlancy, you are right. This is a duplicate of Backup on File Close Excel VBA which I had messed up on posting the code & someone corrected it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** here is the "ThisWorkbook" module, which is where you should add this code:

[image]

**Original response:** Add the following into the "ThisWorkbook" module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Dim awb As Workbook
Dim BackupFileName As String
Dim i As Long
Dim OK As Boolean
Dim SameFileFormat As XlFileFormat

If TypeName(ActiveWorkbook) = "Nothing" Then Exit Sub
SameFileFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat '<~ grab the file format
Set awb = ActiveWorkbook
If awb.Path = "" Then
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show
Else
    BackupFileName = awb.FullName
    i = 0
    While InStr(i + 1, BackupFileName, ".") > 0
        i = InStr(i + 1, BackupFileName, ".")
    Wend
If i > 0 Then BackupFileName = Left(BackupFileName, i - 1)
BackupFileName = BackupFileName & "-bak" '<~ add "-bak" to the end of the filename
OK = False
On Error GoTo NotAbleToSave
With awb
    Application.StatusBar = "Saving the workbook backup"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    .SaveAs Filename:=BackupFileName, FileFormat:=SameFileFormat '<~ save occurs here
    OK = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.StatusBar = "Backup saved!"
    Application.StatusBar = False
End With

End If

NotAbleToSave:
   Set awb = Nothing
   Application.StatusBar = False
   If Not OK Then
    MsgBox "Backup Copy Not Saved!", vbExclamation, ThisWorkbook.Name
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To be honest, I am not familiar with Private Subs so I got stuck trying to test your code. I do not want to hide the code. I want backups to be created on file close.

Comment: Hey @BenC, though it seems tricky it really is not. Just add exactly what is written above into the "ThisWorkbook" module as pictured above in my edited response

Comment: I guess my issue is in Macro Name & Macros in: because I get a Sub (with new name) below the Private Sub. That's where Im getting stuck.

Comment: Can you send me a screenshot of this @BenC? I'm not sure I understand what is occurring here...

Comment: Hey @DanWagner,mhtml:file://C:\Users\BChingono\Desktop\Backup Code.MHT!cid:A366FFEC92B546A4ACF29C0D570DFDCB@dns

Comment: Hey @DanWagner, please disregard the above.

Comment: ![ScreenShot][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/J6HGy.jpg

Comment: Hey @BenC, I apologize for not being so clear in my update above. I have modified your screenshot, move the code from "Module1" to "ThisWorkbook" as shown in the answer above

Comment: I see my problem @DanWagner. I was trying to run the private sub from the VBE and it would open the create Macro window. I stop doing that & your code is working good on file close. Thanks a bunch for your patience.

Comment: Glad I could help @BenC, welcome to SO!